# Table creating more table rather than a new row

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I am trying to populate my React Bootstrap table data using a single array of objects. I want to create a new row for each obj and with one table header for each column, but instead it's creating new tables instead.

I tried to move the map function ("this.props.data.map((person, key) =>") inside where  is called/rendered and few other places, so it doesn't call the  componenet multiple times, but I am having hard time with the syntax.

```
const columns = [{
    dataField: 'id',
    text: 'ID'
}, {
    dataField: 'firstName',
    text: 'First Name'
}, {
    dataField: 'lastName',
    text: 'Last Name',
    sort: true
}, {
    dataField: 'birthDate',
    text: 'Birth Date'
}, {
    dataField: 'email',
    text: 'Email'
}];

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {this.props.data.map((person, key) =>
                    <div key={key} >
                        <BootstrapTable
                            hover
                            condensed={true}
                            bootstrap4={true}
                            keyField='id'
                            data={person}
                            columns={columns}
                            />
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: "data" property accepts an array or just object?

Comment: It looks like it accepts a single Array object. 
https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/table-props.html#columns-required-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to map through the array. All you need to do is put `this.props.data` into the `data` field.

```
data={this.props.data}
```

Then, as long as the keys i.e `firstName, lastName` etc... are in the objects, it shouldl print the table for you.

This is assuming your array looks like:

```
[{firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Sagget',...}, {firstName: 'George', lastName: 'Bobbish',... }]
```

Full return statement:

```
return(
        <div>
             <BootstrapTable
              hover
              condensed={true}
              bootstrap4={true}
              keyField='id'
              data={this.props.data}
              columns={columns}
              />
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Thank you. You're right, I just had to put this.props.data into data!

Comment: No problem. I've had to do some serious battle with this component. Best of luck!

Comment: Nice! This is exactly what I was suspecting.